# includepdf into .tex file but crop each page's header off

Tags: pdftex, crop

I was hoping to find a way to insert several (many) pages of a pdf but crop off the header (with the date, filename, etc.). I'm using

```
\subsection{Notes}
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=8-20,pagecommand=\subsection{blub}]{Notes.pdf}
```

but maybe I need to use `pdftk` somehow to do the batch cropping?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `\includepdf` accepts all the options that `\includegraphics` does; so `trim=l b r t,clip` should work (unless you're using XeLaTeX that, currently, doesn't support cropping). You have to compute the four dimensions, but probably `l` and `r` should be 0, while `t` and `b` depend on the document you have.

Comment: Aaah. thanks @egreg! I used: \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=8-10,clip,trim=5mm 5mm 10mm 10mm]{Notes.pdf}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\includepdf` accepts all the options that `\includegraphics` does; so

```
trim=left bottom right top,clip
```

should work (unless you're using XeLaTeX that, currently, doesn't support cropping). You have to compute the four dimensions, but probably `left` and `right` should be 0, while `top` and `bottom` depend on the document you have.

Example (from your comment)

```
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=8-10,clip,trim=5mm 5mm 10mm 10mm]{Notes.pdf}
```

Comment: this crops the content, but the page size remains the same

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, never claimed differently.

Comment: Sorry, I understood it was a different problem.