# Border around included pdf

Tags: pdfpages

I have some appendices in my report and I want to add a border around the document to make it more clear it's not a part of the document.

I am using the `pdfpages` package to include the pdf files.

Currently I am using this to include the pdf:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,frame,scale=.95,pagecommand={}]{bijlagen/pva.pdf}
```

I'm using the `frame` option which draws a border around, it gives me this result:
[image: framed document]

As you can see the page number and the header of the "base document" is showing up inside the frame, and I do want them to show up. But what I actually want is the border to be smaller, somewhat like this:

[image: border as I want it]

I've tried doing it with

```
\begin{framed}
\includepdf[pages=-,frame,scale=.95,pagecommand={}]{bijlagen/pva.pdf}
\end{framed}
```

But that doesn't work because the pdf is multiple pages and it tries to put everything one the same place. (it might work with only one page, but I didn't test it)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76213/36296

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the comment of samcarter I manage to solve it somewhat:

[image]

With these options:

```
\includepdf[
    clip=0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm,
    trim=20mm 40mm 20mm 15mm,
    pages=-,
    frame,
    scale=.65,
    pagecommand={}
 ]{
    bijlagen/pva.pdf
 }
```

It is a bit small, so I have to fine tune these values some more.

Comment: Please always post complete code people can compile i.e. minimal but working.