# Adjust Frame Option of pdfpages-Package

Tags: minipage, appendices, geometry, pdfpages, framed

I'm currently writing a report for university and want to include some pdf documents as appendices. I'm using pdfpages (of course) to include these pdfs but i ran into one small problem:

I scaled the pdf pages down a little bit, so that i can keep the pagenumbering of my report visible.
Also, i'm including the first page of each pdf in a minipage, so that i can print the name of the appendix-element (`\chapter{}`)

I want to make these pdf pages stand out a little bit. the pdfpages-Packages gives the `frame` option, that draws a small border around the pdf page. However, not the whole page is inside the frame (See picture below)

What am i doing wrong?

I've taken several instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20972874/9076590) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356008/151015).

[image: Screenshot]

Example Code:

```
\chapter{Unterrichtsentwurf E2GS2}\label{append:E2GS2}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\includepdf[clip=0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm,
    trim=20mm 40mm 20mm 15mm,
    frame,
    width=.7\textwidth,
    pagecommand={}
    ]{../../Unterrichtsvorbereitung/E2GS2/Leitermagnetfeld.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\includepdf[clip=0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm,
    trim=20mm 40mm 20mm 15mm,
    pages=2-,
    width=.9\textwidth,
    frame,
    pagecommand={}
    ]{../../Unterrichtsvorbereitung/E2GS2/Leitermagnetfeld.pdf}
```

Furthermore, í noticed, that when i include my pdf in two parts like this, omitting the `frame` option in the first part, but including it in the second part still draws a border around the page i included in the first part! Can someone explain, why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending much too much time on this issue, i basically came to think that it's not possible to achieve what i wanted - at least not without redefining or extending something in the pdfpages-package.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over a similar, but not identical, issue: I wanted to have more control over how the frame is drawn.
I simply used TikZ to draw the frame (and not the `frame` option directly). In case anyone is interested, here's my solution.

```
\tikzset{
    myborder/.pic = {
        \path [-, draw=green, line width=2pt] 
            ($(current page.north west)+(1pt,-1pt)$) -|
            ($(current page.south east)+(-1pt,1pt)$) -| 
            cycle;
    }
}
\includepdf[
    pages={11,14}, 
    pagecommand={%
        \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{%
            \pic {myborder};
        }%
    },
    width=.99\paperwidth
]{other.pdf}%
```

This needs `calc` and `positioning` TikZ libraries, I think:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
```